# Where can I read the bidi algorithm implementation?

Tags: bidirectional-support

I'm interested in reading the part of the Emacs source code where the bidi (bidirectionality) algorithm is implemented. Where is it?

P.S. I've never looked at the Emacs source code before, and I'm a rather amateur programmer.

Comment: Your last phrase ("*so please keep it as simple and user-friendly as possible*") does not apply here. You are not asking for a presentation of the algorithm here. You are asking for a pointer to such a description elsewhere. I removed that phrase, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, largely in `src/bidi.c` and `src/xdisp.c`. The latter implements the bulk of the redisplay, and there are numerous relevant comments about the bidi implementation in its header commentary (search for "Bidirectional display").

- http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/xdisp.c
- http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/bidi.c

I've never looked at this code myself, so there may be additional files of interest, but these will make for a good start.